# Is there an alternative to using “man” repetitively?

Tags: style

I’ve noticed that when using *man* it can become extremely repetitive:

> Wenn man solche Goethe-Institut-Prüfungen machen will, muss man bereits wissen, auf welcher Stufe man ist.

*Das klingt für mich grausam.* Also, my teacher told me Germans don’t like repetitiveness in writing. We had to make a *Bewerbungspaket* and in my cover letter I used *Erfahrung/en* 3 times and she took off a point or two, because she said you shouldn’t use the same word more than once. I know that you aren’t supposed to replace *man* with *er* so does that repetitiveness not matter for *man*?

Comment: Oh, nice question, I've asked this all my life. The only alternative I'm aware of is *Nominalisierung*, i.e. dropping the subject and let the verbs become nouns.

Comment: I'm just wondering is there any general way to avoid using man over and over again in a sentence

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are is no general alternative for *man*-sentences, but different ones for different usages.

Passive constructions:

> (direct transformation, except for the *is*-clause, that cannot be transformed into passive) Wenn eine solche Goethe-Institut-Prüfung gemacht werden will, muss die eigene Stufe bereits gewusst werden.
>
> (transformation into proper style) Wenn eine solche Goethe-Institut-Prüfung angestrebt wird, muss die eigene Stufe bereits bekannt sein.

Nominalization:

> (direct transformation) Für das Machen einer solchen Goethe-Institut-Prüfung ist das Wissen der eigenen Stufe notwendig.
>
> (transformation into proper style) Für das Absolvieren einer solchen Goethe-Institut-Prüfung ist die Kenntnis der eigenen Stufe notwendig.

Relative sentences:

> Wer eine solche Goethe-Institut-Prüfung machen will, muss die eigene Stufe wissen (kennen). (Here, no transformation is needed, as it is already proper style.)

Passive constructions and Nominalization permit only a partial substitution of the *man*s. Relative sentences don’t.

Personal order of preference for the given situation:

1. The original sentence with three *man*s, as the repetition of *man* inside a single sentence is not a question of style but of grammar.
2. The relative sentence, as it changes the style the least.
3. Passive construction and Nominalization as even the improved versions are rather clumsy.

Answer (score 9):

Stilistisch ist ein mehrfaches Verwenden von *man* so unproblematisch wie der mehrfache Gebrauch von *er/sie/es* oder *der/die/das*. Es ist so gewöhnlich, dass man es als Muttersprachler gar nicht registriert.

Allgemein wird stilistische Abwechslung sehr geschätzt, aber oft gibt es keine gleichwertige Alternative, und dann ist es meist besser präzise zu sein als abwechslungsreich. In einem Artikel zum Klimawandel kann man vielleicht noch Erderwärmung benutzen, aber vielleicht braucht man das Substantiv acht- bis zehnmal – da ist eine Wiederholung kaum vermeidbar.

Comment: Alternativen zu *man* sind nicht weniger wert

Comment: Would you mind adding a translation into English as the question is written in English.

Comment: @Em1: Ich bin nach wie vor der Meinung, dass der größte gemeinsame Nenner hier die dt. Sprache ist, nicht die Englische, und dass Antworten allen Besuchern zu gute kommen sollten, nicht nur den Englischsprachigen.

Comment: @userunknown Sprich, die Antworten sollen nur den Deutschsprachigen zu gute kommen. Paradox.

Comment: @Em1: Was ist daran paradox? Dass man Deutsch lernt beim Verwenden?

Answer (score 8):

I don’t think that striving toward low to no repetitiveness is particularly German. It is a question of style. Let me use an image from biology here. After a nerve fired (was activated) it turns numb for some time. Same for language. Repetition can be boring. However, the rate at which a word becomes boring varies quite a lot and depends on the word itself but also on the text. You can not avoid “repetitive” if that’s your topic. Some people, even journalists, try to use no repetition at all and what they wind up with are texts where everyone can immediately tell that the author went out of his way and into the synonym dictionary to avoid using the same word twice.

Anyway, *man* is one of the words that can be repeated a million times. It is a bit like *ich*. If you talk about yourself you won’t replace *ich* with *my being*, *Mr Something* or *the man who tells you this* … you just use *ich* and that’s it.

Your sentence isn’t bad. I wouldn’t even notice the triple *man*. There are million ways to rephrase it so I’ll just add the one they all missed out on so far … the verb first conditional structure:

> Will man solche Goethe-Institut-Prüfungen machen, sollte man die eigene Stufe kennen.

Comment: For example, if you had strictly avoided the repetition of "boring" in this answer, it would have become less comprehensible.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to avoid *man*:

- Use of pronoun *wer*:

> Wer solche Goethe-Institut Prüfungen machen will, …

- General avoiding of pronouns:

> Wenn solche Goethe-Institut Prüfungen gemacht werden wollen, …

- Redrafting by the use of valid generic terms:

> Wenn Schüler solche Goethe-Institut Prüfungen machen wollen, …
>
> …, muss das Wissen dazu bereits vorhanden sein, …

- Use of impersonal *es* with *Infinitiv mit zu*

> …, ist es gut zu wissen, …

- Use of alternatives to *man* (other indefinite pronoun)

> …, auf welcher Stufe so etwas ist.
>
> …, auf welcher Stufe das ist.
>
> …, auf welcher Stufe es/jemand/einer ist.

Comment: Da die Prüfungen selbst keinen eigenen Willen haben ist Alternative 2 m.E. schlecht. Bsp. 2 setzt den Gedanken zu frei fort und drückt sich wie die anderen Bsp. davor, die Alternative durchzudeklinieren, und zu zeigen, was mit den anderen 2 mans passiert. Bsp. 4 läßt offen, ob es nicht mit `... , auf welcher Stufe man ist.` komplettiert wird. `So etwas`. wie im letzten Block, kommt wohl nicht in Frage. So etwas was? Ebenso 'auf welcher Stufe das ist'. Die Frage war, auf welcher Stufe man, also der Prüfling ist. Dass dieser nicht notwendig auf der Stufe der Prfg. ist, ist der Witz einer Prfng.

Comment: Bsp. 2 steht im Passiv, spricht also nicht wie entgegnet aus sich selbst heraus. Bsp. 4 ist einfach nur eine Lösung für den mittleren Teil, und man kann das in Teil 3 mit *man* komplettieren, muss man aber nicht; das gilt natürlich für alle anderen Bsp. genauso. Der letzte Block ist Ansichtssache, d.h. dass einer einem Level nicht gewachsen ist, kann sich indirekt auch daraus ergeben, dass das Level zu hoch ist. Ja, man kann hier kleinlich sein, aber ich habe hier mehr den Schwerpunkt auf die sprachlichen Mittel gelegt und deshalb beides angeboten.

Comment: -1, weil m.E. eine grammatikalischen Konstruktion nicht hilfreich ist, wenn das Ergebnis stilistisch unbrauchbar ist. Mindestens bei "Wenn solche Prüfungen gemacht werden wollen" und bei "auf welcher Stufe so etwas ist" **muss** man einem Nicht-Muttersprachler m.E. darauf hinweisen, dass diese Formulierungen nicht für den täglichen Gebrauch geeignet sind.

Comment: @tohuwawohu: ich stimme "unbrauchbar" und "nicht für den täglichen Gebrauch" nicht zu. I.d.R. wird vorzugsweise *man* verwendet, aber das sind trotzdem gültige Ausweichvarianten. Subjektiv werden hier sicher verschiedene Alternativen bevorzugt.

Answer (score 3):

One alternative is nominalization, i.e. dropping the subject and let the verbs become nouns. You can play with the *degree of nominalization*, so to say, as follows:

Variant 1 (dropping only one *man*):

> Wenn man solche Goethe-Institut-Prüfungen machen will, muss man bereits sein Niveau kennen.

Variant 2 (making all *man* dissapear):

> (Eine) Vorausetzung für die Teilnahme an den Prüfungen des Goethe-Instituts ist die Kenntnis der eigenen Stufe.

Variant 3 (leaving only one *man*):

> Für die Teilnahme an den Goethe-Institut-Prüfungen wird vorausgesetzt, dass man seine eigene Stufe kennt.

**Edit:** Actually, variant 1 is not a restult of nominalization, but by just joinig the two last sentences. But the other variants are.

Comment: So habe ich es gemeint. Man muss nur die Gleichung `Eigenes Niveau = zu bestehendes Niveau minus 1 Niveau` lösen :D.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

> I’m just wondering is there any general way to avoid using man over and over again in a sentence.

I don’t think that repeating *man* is a big problem on its own, but I do think that phrases become clearer and more vivid if we use it sparingly. You can (almost) always go ahead and talk about the actor, the person that is hidden beneath the stealth cap of *man*. In many cases it is  — you! It is incredible how many people say *man*, but actually just mean *I*. If this is the case, you should better say

> Wenn ich solche Goethe-Institut-Prüfungen machen will, muss ich bereits wissen, auf welcher Stufe ich bin.

or (avoiding one of the three *ich*):

> Um solche Goethe-Institut-Prüfungen zu machen, muss ich bereits wissen, auf welcher Stufe ich bin.

But maybe you really wanted to speak about other persons. You could then try to find a general (or, *pars pro toto*, just typical) name, category, profession etc. that describes these persons

> Ein Schüler / Student / Interessent / (maybe context suggests even more), der solche Goethe-Institut-Prüfungen machen will, muss bereits wissen, auf welcher Stufe er ist.

And finally, you can use at least *jemand* or a relative clause with *wer*, and you will at least avoid the repitition, and have a *personal* pronoun in the last part:

> Jemand der / Wer solche Goethe-Institut-Prüfungen machen will, muss bereits wissen, auf welcher Stufe er ist.